# bashrc if: Expression Syntax error

Tags: bash, unix

I have written the following .bashrc :

```
# .bashrc
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions


function up( )
{
LIMIT=$1
P=$PWD
for ((i=1; i <= LIMIT; i++))
do
    P=$P/..
done
cd $P
export MPWD=$P
}

function back( )
{
LIMIT=$1
P=$MPWD
for ((i=1; i <= LIMIT; i++))
do
    P=${P%/..}
done
cd $P
export MPWD=$P
}
```

However, after saving, when I did `source .bashrc`, i got the following error:   `if: Expression Syntax.`

What am I doing wrong ? I googled a while but no avail.

Comment: check if your shell is bash using echo $SHELL

Comment: @JohnTortugo Thanks, I was using the c shell and making changes in the bashrc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if: Expression Syntax
```

is not an error bash would give you. Perhaps your shell is not bash. In fact, as long as `if` stands alone, any error would not be with `if` itself:

```
$ if [somethingswrong]; then fail; fi # error, then `[` command must have space around it.
-bash: [somethingswrong]: command not found
```

You can check your shell by echoing `$SHELL`, and you can check which version of bash with `$BASH_VERSION`. (If the latter is unset, your shell is not bash.)

Comment: Thanks, I was using the c shell and making changes in the bashrc.