# adding non standard library to @inc in PERL in tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, module

I am trying to use a few perl modules which are located in my own directory. 
I read that I need to add the "export" command in this form -

```
export PERL5LIB=PERL5LIB:/location/of/personal/modules
```

However I was doing this in bash, and once I tried to source bash after the modification I started to get the "if: Expression Syntax" error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440105/bashrc-if-expression-syntax-error) tells me that it means my shell is not bash. I queried by echo $SHELL, which gives me tcsh ( I guess its the C shell)

I opened tcsh with the intention of adding the "export" command as written above, however its completely blank and I am now confused as to how to add the non standard directory to @INC.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the equivalent `tcsh` expression is

```
setenv PERL5LIB PERL5LIB:/location/of/personal/modules
```

Though I expect that line was supposed to be

```
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/location/of/personal/modules
```

which would mean you want

```
setenv PERL5LIB $PERL5LIB:/location/of/personal/modules
```

But if you don't have anything in the `PERL5LIB` variable already then you can just use

```
setenv PERL5LIB /location/of/personal/modules
```